# Less bad way to shortly getting an array offset in php

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management, offset

**Context**

In php, we access (as in many others languages) elements of arrays (or string, when one char needed)
by targeting their offset using the square bracket syntax []
or some native functions like array_push, array_pop... etc.

Actually, when i need to write shortened code, i proceed like the following:

Here only the first offset is needed

```
$b = explode('_', $a)[0];
```

It works, but i've always wondered if it's impacting on performance or if it's ethically correct.
I've not found (or badly searched ?), in duplicate post list, then
i've try to bench to analyse the behavior. link to [my bench](http://sprunge.us/NNba)

I dont know i this bench is right coded but it appear :
static access takes less time (half less time) and cheapest memory,
hmmm it's cheapest memory, only when i increase the number of iterations in bench... I am not very sure of anything.
Logically, array_shift should the following path, access the first item, shrink the memory to shift, or simply change item pointer address ?

According to you, what is the least bad method ?

## Method 0

```
$b = explode('_', $a)[0];
```

## Method 1

```
$b = array_shift(explode('_', $a));
```

## Method 2

```
$b = explode('_', $a);
$b = array_shift($a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about getting an array offset:
 - To access first element:

```
array_shift(explode('_', $a))
```

of course, will be slower and more memory consuming than

```
explode('_', $a)[0]
```

because **array_shift** function extracts first element from array and comes to ***re-indexing*** all the other elements.
If you interested in performance of indexed arrays then consider `SplFixedArray` as it saves about ***60%*** of memory.

Comment: Oh thanks for sharing, never heard of this SPL class, excellent !
ok but then imbricate shift(explode( use shared memory ? or it's as gourmand as to variabilize each of them ?

Comment: actually, I didn't completely understand your last phrase. Did you mean: "Do I have to store the initial array in additional variable before getting it's offset?"

Comment: sorry, my bad. Not exactly, i think i stumble on an ethical problem: at work, override the initialization of a variable is perceived as a crime.. hence my question :)  finally, my method_0 is not a bad programming practices ?

Comment: method_0 could be rarely used only in the firm belief that result of 'expode' function is array in 100%. In most cases it can't be a good practice at all

Comment: and since i always check with is_array before, it is not a bad practice and are faster :)  Thanks  for your opinion, and pretty spl class !